# overriding fullcalendar javascript functions which is in another script

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, overriding, overwrite

I am newbie in js and I want to override/overwrite some [fullcalendar](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar) functions from another script (my-fullcalendar.js) to make some changes in it for myself. for example function names are :

> formatRange and oldMomentFormat.

formatRange is accessible from this.$.fullCalendar.formatRange but oldMomentFormat is not accessible via this kind of chain. But even when I do something like this in my-fullcalendar.js:

```
;(function () {
      function MyformatRange(date1, date2, formatStr, separator, isRTL) {
          console.log( "MyformatRange");
          //other parts is exactly the same
          // ...
      }
      this.$.fullCalendar.formatRange=MyformatRange;
      console.log(this);
})();
```

nothing happens because no log is generated and even line by line tracing does not pass from here. but when observing "this" in console log MyformatRange replaced by original formatRange.
another problem is how can I override/overwrite oldMomentFormat function which is not in window hierarchy to access (or I can not find it) ??

Comment: That code should work. Make sure that everything is being loaded in the correct order.

Comment: how could I be sure that everything is being loaded in the correct order? my js scripts are in this order : <script src='../dist/fullcalendar.js'></script> <script src='../dist/my-fullcalendar.js'></script> . and what about oldMomentFormat??

Answer (score 3):

OK, let's simplify the problem. In essence, you have this situation:

```
var makeFunObject = function () {
  var doSomething = function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
  };

  var haveFun = function () {
    doSomething( "fun!");
  };

  return {
    doSomething : doSomething,
    haveFun : haveFun
  };
};
```

In other words you have a function that is creating a closure. Inside that closure are two "private" functions, one of which calls the other. But both functions seem to be "exposed" in the returned object.

You write some code:

```
var myFunObject = makeFunObject();
myFunObject.haveFun(); // fun!
```

Yep, seems to work just fine. Now let's *replace* the `doSomething` function in that returned object and call `haveFun` again:

```
myFunObject.doSomething = function (msg) {
  console.log("My new function: " + msg);
};
myFunObject.haveFun(); // fun! <== wait what?
```

But wait! The new replacement function is not being called! That's right: the `haveFun` function was expressly written to call the internal function. It in fact knows nothing about the exposed function in the object at all.

That's because you cannot replace the internal, private function in this way (you cannot replace it at all, in fact, not without altering the original code).

Now draw back to the FullCalendar code: you are replacing the external function in the object, but the internal function is the one *that is called by every other function inside FullCalendar*.

Comment: So you mean there is no way to override formatRange and oldMomentFormat and write a plugin for fullCalendar?? my purpose was to do my changes as plugin for fullCalendar and not to change the original code.

Comment: There are two questions there. 1. There is no way to override those functions from the outside. 2. Of course you can write plugins for FullCalendar just like you can for, say, jQuery itself. but in doing so you have to accept what it does internally; you are in effect, providing extra functionality above and beyond what it already gives, and what's already there won't "know" about the plugin..

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question, but I was butting my head against this same problem when I wanted to override the `getEventTimeText` function.

I was able to accomplish this, from inside my own JS file, like so:

```
$.fullCalendar.Grid.mixin({
    getEventTimeText: function (range, formatStr, displayEnd) {
        //custom version of this function
    }
});
```

So, in terms of the function you were trying to override, you should be able to do it with:

```
$.fullCalendar.View.mixin({
    formatRange: function (range, formatStr, separator) {
        //custom formatRange function
    }
});
```

**Note:** Make sure this runs before where you actually create the calendar. Also note that you need to make sure to override the function in the right place. For example, `getEventTimeText` was in `$.fullCalendar.Grid`, while `formatRange` is in `$.fullCalendar.View`.

Hopefully this helps other people who end up on this question.